# return static list from static function cause link error

Tags: c++

hi i know another post about link errorr and static keyword in c++ but i think i have done everything right

i declare and define my function in PluginCollection.h

```
#ifndef PLUGINCOLLECTION_H
#define PLUGINCOLLECTION_H

#include <QList>
#include "PluginA.h" //this include Plugin.h


namespace PluginCollection
{
  static QList<Plugin *> get_plugins();
}

QList<Plugin*> PluginCollection::get_plugins()
{
  static QList<Plugin*> list;
  list.push_back(new PluginA());
  return list;
}
#endif // PLUGINCOLLECTION_H
```

and i have link error about override member function of derived class
so if my class Plugin have this pure virtual member function:

```
 virtual QString get()=0; 
  virtual QString set()=0;
  virtual QString    print()=0;
```

i have:

- **link error external simbol QString __cdecl PluginA::get(...)**
- **link error external simbol QString __cdecl PluginA::set(...)**
- **link error external simbol QString __cdecl PluginA::print(...)**

and then call it in mainwindow.cpp constructor:

```
  ui->setupUi(this);

  ui->tabWidget->clear();
  for(Plugin* p : PluginCollection::get_plugins())
    {
      build_tab_from_plugin(p);
    }
```

p.s.:i'm using qt creator with msvc14

Comment: this is not how you use static. a static function is static to some class or module, not globally declared function inside a namespace

Comment: @DavidHaim, normally yes. But you could place a static function into a namespace in its TU, for organizational purposes. However, I'm aware this is not what the OP is attempting.

Comment: Is your shift key broken, tuttomax? This isn't texting time with your school mates. Sentences begin with a capital letter.

Comment: so i shouldn't use static in namespace anyway the i have link error also without it

Comment: my purpose is to initialize only once time the list where i save plugins

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, your plugin-class (which you create instances of) has pure virtual member functions. Therefore the linker cannot know where these member functions are. But these member functions are required for the linker.

You have to have at least one implementation of every pure-virtual member function to be able to create an instance of this class.

If you use

```
virtual QString get(){return QString();}
virtual QString set(){return QString();}
virtual QString print(){return QString();}
```

instead and your code links successfully, this is your problem.

By the way, `set` should set an value and `print` should print something. So it should look something like this:

```
virtual QString get(){return m_myQStringMember;}
virtual void set(QString& val){m_myQStringMember = val;}
virtual void print(){ qDebug() << m_myQStringMember;}
```

and if you want an string representation, you can use something like this:

```
    virtual QString toQString(){return QString("MyClass{ m_myQStringMember=") + m_myQStringMember + "}";}
```

Comment: i use some name for showing the problem i know i have to insert some parameters

Comment: Sometimes `clean` followed by `execute qmake` can help. If not you need to provide more code - try to break it down to an minimal example. Often you find the error while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with this

```
QList<Plugin *> get_plugins()
  {
    static QList<Plugin*> list {new PluginA() }; 
    return list;
  }
```

why didn't this work?

```
 QList<Plugin *> get_plugins()
      {
        static QList<Plugin*> list;
        list.push_back(new PluginA());
        return list;
      }
```

both list are initialized the  former with list initialization the latter with default constructor.